# Spring MongoDB populate references

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to create a reference to another model in Spring MognoDB.

I have a list of documents previously inserted into MongoDB using Mongoose so the references look like this:

```json
{
  ...
  address: ObjectId("5f596acb8ea1d54128016e97")
}
```

Following the Spring MongoDB documentation, I created two models:

```java
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Person{

    @Id
    private String id;

    ... other attributes

    @DBRef
    private Address address;

}
```

Second model:

```java
@Document(collection = "address")
public class Address{

    @Id
    private String id;

    ... other attributes

}
```

However this fails to return a document, showing the following error:

`No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] to type [....models.Address]`

Any idea how to solve this problem?

I also tried changing the `id` type to `ObjectId` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try writing a custom type converter? See this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters.writer